# how can i do singleton dependency injection while creating new object everytime?

Tags: java, spring

I've got a class:

```
    public class Base
    {
    private MyExecutor executor;
    }
```

How do i create new instances of class Base using new operator and want to use the same singleton instance of MyExecutor injected through spring??
Please suggest.

Comment: I think bydefault every bean is singleton, you dont need to do anything here

Comment: @VKSingla I believe you are missing the point. I BELIEVE the question is stating how to create instances of `Base` using the `new` operator in java code (as opposed to declaring it as a bean in spring) using the spring singleton instance of the executor.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the executor as non-prototype (ie. don't make it prototype as singleton is the default). Grab the bean from the ApplicationContext, pass it into the constructor of `Base`.

Another option would be to store the singleton instance as a static field of `MyExecutor` from the constructor being called by Spring. Then provide a `getInstance` static method.

Comment: I think bydefault every bean is singleton, you dont need to do anything here

Comment: Correct, I was just making sure that it was not marked as prototype.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Spring does by default, it injects the same instance of a bean. Eg belows B1 and B2 will get the same instance of MyExecutor bean simply by default, that is unless you change MyExecutor bean scope from `singleton` to `prototype` or other.

```
public class B1 {
    @Autowired
    private MyExecutor executor;
...

public class B2 {
    @Autowired
    private MyExecutor executor;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
   ApplicationContext ctx = ...
    YourClass someBeanNotCreatedBySpring = ...
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(
        someBeanNotCreatedBySpring,
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_AUTODETECT, true);
```

You can use `@Autowired` and so on within YourClass to specify fields to be injected etc.

Or you can add following annotations to Base and `@Autowired`  to specify fields to be injected

```
@Configurable(preConstruction=true,dependencyCheck=true,autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@EnableSpringConfigured
```

and following in XMl COnfiguration

```
<context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver" aspectj-weaving="on"/>
```

or

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect"/>
```

Key concept is to enable `Load time weaving`

[Source](http://www.olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/)